# Remote shutdown from batch file

Tags: batch-file, networking

I am currently trying to write a short Batch file to shutdown a PC connected to the network. I use the `shutdown` command with the `-m` switch, as in the following example:

```
shutdown -r -m \\192.168.0.3 -t 60
```

The syntax seems to be correct, but the terminal returns with the following statement:

> Unable to find the network path

So, although there is a PC connected to that IP, the terminal returns with an error.

How can I solve this issue? Does it need a particular background service to be turned on?

Comment: What happens when you `ping 192.168.0.3` ?

Comment: All the packages sent to 192.168.0.3 return; that is no data loss.

Answer (score 0):

try with put u'r -r parameter after comp name

```
shutdown –m \\computername –r –f –c “I’m restarting your computer for maintenance.  Please save your work now.” –t 120
```

to call this tool with windows interface, type `shutdown -i` on cmd

Answer (score -2):

```
set ip=
set seconds= 
shutdown -m \\%ip% -r  -f -t %seconds%
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but anyway your statements don't solve the issue because they just replace an already defined parameter with a variable to be defined.